# Android App Content Host

Tags: android

I see some Android app has a feature: the app provides a IP address and port number. User opens the browser on PC with the IP and port. User can view app content and download data file and images in the app from a PC browser. How to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: maybe try searching for "android web server example"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the library you need to include in your Android app:

https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd

Just tested and it works great

Comment: Not sure yet. I think you point me to the right direction. I will vote for you.